# Como criar um script de movimento para uma div?

Tags: javascript

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Character Movement Script</title>
    <style>

        body {
            background-color: rgb(166, 166, 172);
        }

        div#player {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.673);
            border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="player"></div>

<script>

var player = window.document.querySelector("#player");

window.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
  player.style.left = "10px";
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer quando eu pressionasse no botão da seta a direita a `div#player` começasse a ir para a direita quando eu apertar o botão da esquerda ela vai para a esquerda e a mesma coisa vai acontecer para as seta cima e baixo. O problema e que não estou conseguindo resolver isso, pois o que acontece é que quando eu aperto em qualquer tecla a `div#player` vai `10px` para a direita e quando eu aperto de novo ela não vai mais e eu não quero isso, só vai ir para uma determida direção apenas com as teclas direcionais um exemplo é em um vídeo que eu vi no [YouTube](https://youtu.be/kXiImu6jCk4), só muda que eu queria nesse caso para cima, direta, baixo e esquerda como eu faria isso?

Comment: @Sam não era isso que eu queria! a pergunta é diferente da pergunta que você duplico.

Comment: E a pergunta que você duplicou o cara está usando Jquery e quero JS puro, não tem nada a ver.

Comment: `player.style.left = "10px"`, aqui você está definindo que a posição será 10px da esquerda. Para o movimento você não deve usar um valor absoluto, mas ir incrementando.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss como assim eu não entendi?

Comment: Brincando com a ideia... https://jsfiddle.net/acwoss/akg426L8/

Comment: considere usar o elemento [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial)

Comment: @vik necessariamente ele não precisa usar o `canvas` para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, é bem simples, mas para você pode ser que seja um pouco mais complexo de se fazer, mas irei comentar cada parte do código já que você está tendo dificudades de implementar isso no seu projeto.

1. Bom, primeiro de tudo dentro da tag `script` inicialize três variáveis que iremos usar futuramente no script.

   ```
   var horizontalAxisX = 0;
   var verticalAxisY = 0;
   var pixels = "px";
   ```
2. Em seguida, adicione o evento `keydown` no `window` e chame a função `playerMovement`, você fez basicamente a mesma coisa, só muda que você chamou uma função anônima.

   ```
   window.addEventListener("keydown", playerMovement);
   ```
3. Agora dentro da função `playerMovement` crie uma variável `player` com o valor fazendo referência a `div="player"` lá no HTML.

   ```
   var player = window.document.getElementById("player");
   ```
4. E também necessitaremos de ter uma variável que guarde o valor da tecla pressionada para assim futuramente podermos usar esse valor. Então crie uma variável `key` e armazene o valor `event.keyCode` que é o valor da tecla pressionada armazenda na variável `key`.

   ```
   var key = event.keyCode;
   ```
5. Agora vem a parte mais fácil que é usar uma estrutura de condição que seria o `if`, nós vamos comparar o valor da variável `key` com o valor da tecla que queremos. Vale ressaltar uma coisa cada tecla do teclado possui um código(número) esse código é o que nós vamos utilizar para fazer a comparação. Caso você não souber o código da tecla que você quer, você poder acessar um site que gere o código da tecla pressionada como, por exemplo o site [keycode](https://keycode.info/) no site apenas pressione a tecla e automaticamente ele vai retornar o código da tecla que você pressionou.

   ```
   if (key == 37) {
       // tecla da esquerda
       // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
   }
   ```
6. O número 37 seria o código da tecla esquerda, precisamos também comparar o código da tecla precionada com as outras teclas que queremos, que seria cima, direita, baixo. Vamos usar um `else if` para isso.

   ```
   else if (key == 38) {
       // tecla de cima
       // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
   }

   else if (key == 39) {
       // tecla da direita
       // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
   }

   else if (key == 40) {
       // tecla de baixo
       // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
   }
   ```
7. Precisamos fazer com que cada vez que a tecla da esquerda for pressionada seja incrementado mais 10, esse 10 tem que ser negativo, porque negativo? mais na frente vai ficar mais claro para você. Dentro do primeiro `if` coloque o seguinte código.

   ```
   horizontalAxisX += -10;
   ```
8. Agora precisamos fazer com que a `div="player"` vá para a esquerda, então teriamos que usar a propriedade `left` do CSS. Só que o valor não vai ser um pixel estático vai ser um pixel dinâmico no caso vamos pegar o código `horizontalAxisX += -10;` e concatenar com a variável `pixels` que tem o valor como uma `String` que é `px`, assim o `left` vai ser `-10px`.

   ```
   player.style.left = horizontalAxisX + pixels;
   ```
9. Esse mesmo conceito de cima, nós iremos inplementar para as outras teclas nós só vai alterar algumas coisas o que vai mudar, vai ser para a tecla top em vez de ser `horizontalAxisX` coloque `verticalAxisY` na linha de cima e de baixo e em vez de ser `left` coloque `top` e na tecla da direita você só vai mudar a variável `horizontalAxisX += 10;` para incrementar um valor positivo `10` e na tecla de baixo você vai colocar `verticalAxisY` na linha de cima e de baixo e coloque ela para incrementar um valor positivo.

   ```
   else if (key == 38) {
        verticalAxisY += -10;
        player.style.top = verticalAxisY + pixels;
   }

   else if (key == 39) {
        horizontalAxisX += 10;
        player.style.left = horizontalAxisX + pixels;
   }

   else if (key == 40) {
        verticalAxisY += 10;
        player.style.top = verticalAxisY + pixels;
   }
   ```

Então o código ficaria por completo assim.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Character Movement Script</title>
    <style>

        body {
            background-color: rgb(166, 166, 172);
        }

        div#player {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.673);
            border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="player"></div>

<script>

var horizontalAxisX = 0;
var verticalAxisY = 0;
var pixels = "px";

window.addEventListener("keydown", playerMovement);

function playerMovement() {
    var player = window.document.getElementById("player");
    var key = event.keyCode;
    
    if (key == 37) {
        // tecla da esquerda
        // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
        horizontalAxisX += -10;
        player.style.left = horizontalAxisX + pixels;
    }

    else if (key == 38) {
        // tecla de cima
        // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
        verticalAxisY += -10;
        player.style.top = verticalAxisY + pixels;
    }

    else if (key == 39) {
        // tecla da direita
        // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
        horizontalAxisX += 10;
        player.style.left = horizontalAxisX + pixels;
    }

    else if (key == 40) {
        // tecla de baixo
        // Se o código da tecla pressionada for igual a 37 execute isso.
        verticalAxisY += 10;
        player.style.top = verticalAxisY + pixels;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Só para dar um extra no código, caso se você quisesse adicionar uma tecla para resetar as posições da `div="player"` e as variáveis usando a tecla espaço ou qualquer outra tecla, você poderia fazer assim.

```
else if (key == 32) {
    player.style.top = "0";
    player.style.left = "0";
    horizontalAxisX = 0;
    verticalAxisY = 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Character Movement Script</title>
    <style>

        body {
            background-color: rgb(166, 166, 172);
        }

        div#player {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.673);
            border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
    
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="player"></div>

<script>

var horizontalAxisX = 0;
var verticalAxisY = 0;
var pixels = "px";

window.addEventListener("keydown", playerMovement);

function playerMovement() {
    var player = window.document.getElementById("player");
    var key = event.keyCode;
    
    if (key == 37) {
        horizontalAxisX += -10;
        player.style.left = horizontalAxisX + pixels;
    }

    else if (key == 38) {
        verticalAxisY += -10;
        player.style.top = verticalAxisY + pixels;
    }

    else if (key == 39) {
        horizontalAxisX += 10;
        player.style.left = horizontalAxisX + pixels;
    }

    else if (key == 40) {
        verticalAxisY += 10;
        player.style.top = verticalAxisY + pixels;
    }

    else if (key == 32) {
        player.style.top = "0";
        player.style.left = "0";
        horizontalAxisX = 0;
        verticalAxisY = 0;
    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

E caso queira aumentar a velocidade da `div#player` é só aumentar o valor do incremento das variáveis `horizontalAxisX` e `verticalAxisY` e caso queira diminuir a velocidade é só diminuir.

Answer (score 2):

Pegue o `keyCode` no evento `keydown`, que são de 37 a 40 os das setas. Então basta pegar a posição atual da div e incrementar ou decrementar `10px` no left se a seta teclada for esquerda ou direita, e no top se a seta teclada for pra cima ou pra baixo.

Exemplo (veja comentários explicativos):

```js
var player = window.document.querySelector("#player");

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
   var tecla = e.keyCode; // código da tecla
   
   // o sinal de "+" é para converter o valor em número
   var pos_x = +player.style.left.replace("px", ""); // retiro o px da posição
   var pos_y = +player.style.top.replace("px", ""); // retiro o px da posição
   var move = 10; // o quanto em pixels vc quer mover

   if(tecla == 37){ // seta ←
      player.style.left = pos_x-move+"px";
   }else if(tecla == 38){ // seta ↑
      player.style.top = pos_y-move+"px";
   }else if(tecla == 39){ // seta →
      player.style.left = pos_x+move+"px";
   }else if(tecla == 40){ // seta ↓
      player.style.top = pos_y+move+"px";
   }
});
```

```css
body {
   background-color: rgb(166, 166, 172);
}

div#player {
   width: 60px;
   height: 60px;
   background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.673);
   border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
   position: relative;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="player"></div>
```